# Comparing AM and PM in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, compare

Im comparing time. See I have this code

```
            DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;

            DateTime StartMorningCleaning = Convert.ToDateTime("6:00:00 AM");
            DateTime EndMorningCleaning = Convert.ToDateTime("6:59:59 AM");

            DateTime StartMorning = Convert.ToDateTime("7:00:00 AM");
            DateTime EndMorning = Convert.ToDateTime("6:59:59 PM");

            DateTime StartNightCleaning = Convert.ToDateTime("7:00:00 PM");
            DateTime EndNightCleaning = Convert.ToDateTime("7:59:59 PM");

            DateTime StartNight = Convert.ToDateTime("8:00:00 PM");
            DateTime BeforeMidnight = Convert.ToDateTime("11:59:59 PM");

            DateTime Midnight = Convert.ToDateTime("12:00:00 AM");
            DateTime EndNight = Convert.ToDateTime("5:59:59 AM");
```

Im trying to compare the current time if its in between Start and end times. The problem is when i go the the PM part it doesnt work and i have no idea why. Starting from StarNightCleaning up to EndNight. Any ideas why? here is my code in the comparing section

```
            if (t1 >= StartMorningCleaning && t1 <= EndMorningCleaning)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Morning Cleaning Time");
                CleaningTime = false;
            }
            else if (t1 >= StartMorning && t1 <= EndMorning)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("MorningTour");
                CleaningTime = true;
            }
            else if (t1 >= StartNightCleaning && t1 <= EndNightCleaning)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Night Cleaning Time");
                CleaningTime = false;
            }
            else if (t1 >= StartNight && t1 <= BeforeMidnight)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NightTour");
                CleaningTime = true;
            }
            else if (t1 >= Midnight && t1 <= EndNight)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NightTour");
                CleaningTime = true;
            }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  When you step through this in your debugger, what specifically happens?  What is `t1`?

Comment: Nothing happens. Literally. No errors was shown. The only part that was working is the `if (t1 >= StartMorningCleaning && t1 <= EndMorningCleaning)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Morning Cleaning Time");
                CleaningTime = false;
            }
            else if (t1 >= StartMorning && t1 <= EndMorning)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("MorningTour");
                CleaningTime = true;
            }` The rest wont work. T1 is the current time of my system

Comment: "Nothing happens.  Literally."  means that the application isn't running at all.  In which case the code isn't the problem because the code is never reached.

Comment: To repeat @David's question: **How** did you **debug**? If `t1` is always `DateTime.Now`, did you really wait until 7:01pm until you debugged what happens when you hit that `else if` part? What happens when you set `t1` to 7:01pm and the debugger hits that `else if` line? "Nothing happens" is something I never observed on my machine, except for total power down.

Comment: It's Actually running. Somehow it never reaches a certain part and its now showing any errors. weird. Also the comparing part is put on a button. whenever i click the button and the time is in between Night cleaning time up to the end of night tour nothing happens. But in morning tour and morning cleaning time it works

Comment: My best guess: check (in your debugger for example), what the `Date` part of `t1` and your `StartNightCleaning` etc. is... I guess that's the problem, `EndNIghtCleaning` might be a day earlier than you think.

Comment: the date part of t1 is actually my computers time. The way i check if all of these parts is working is by changing my computers time. odd why is this not working.

Comment: Aren't there any way on how to compare if my current time is in between let's say 11am to 11pm?

Comment: It's not working because `Convert.ToDateTime()` of a time-only string sets the `Date` part of the result to `DateTime.Today`. So I don't know for the cleaning times, but eg your `Midnight` is last night's midnight, not tonight.

Comment: ohhhhh ok i get it. How do i get the time only? separating it from date so that it only compares the time itself

Comment: Well actually I'm not really sure, I'd need to play around with that. The strange thing is, that `t1` (`DateTime.Now`) does have the corresponding `Date` part, so it should actually work again....I'm confused...brain in sunday-mode.

Comment: So I took the time to try to reproduce that, and for me your code works if `t1` is 7:01pm today, it show the night cleaning time. I tested without changing my computers time, only set `t1` like I needed. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Im going to fiddle around using timespan and see if it works

Comment: Somehow it works when i made a new form. Weird. maybe it's because i change my computers time or a bug happened during debugging. but either way. I made a new form and it worked......

Comment: Im gonna delete this in a few mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Hour property and try reduce logic to numbers.

```
int t1 = DateTime.Now.Hour;             
if (t1 >= 6 && t1 < 7) {
    MessageBox.Show("Morning Cleaning Time");
    CleaningTime = false;
} else if (t1 >= 7 t1 < 19) {
    MessageBox.Show("MorningTour");
    CleaningTime = true;
} else if (t1 >= 19 && t1 < 20) {       //PM
    MessageBox.Show("Night Cleaning Time");
    CleaningTime = false;
} else if (t1 >= 20 && t1 <= 23) {      //PM
    MessageBox.Show("NightTour");
    CleaningTime = true;
} else if (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 5) {       //AM - this if can be just else (remove if part)
    MessageBox.Show("NightTour");
    CleaningTime = true;
}
```

Comment: Yep. This helps!